# I cannot make :hover work in the email sent to Gmail account

Tags: hover, gmail, html-email, pseudo-class

**SOLVED:**  *use the solution from first comment but don't replicate previous emails, but go with: Create > Regular Email > Content (Design Email) > Code your own > Paste in code*

**I wanted to use the CSS :hover pseudoclass in a corporate email sent via MailChimp to Gmail account users** (that's what we use internally in my company). It worked perfectly fine in MailChimp, but after it was sent, it stopped working.

I read online that there's been a long debate about whether Gmail allows for  in the code, as it used only to serve the inline code. But that's not the case, as currently, you can use styling via  and, according to Google customer service pages, you can even have :hover. **I did a double-check and did extra styling in the  to see if it works (adding border), and it is visible in the delivered email.**

But the :hover still does not work. **Thanks for any suggestions on whether it's doable or not, and if yes, can it also be done on mobile?**

Embedded CSS

```
.grow {transition: 0.3s !important;} 
.grow:hover {background-color: #298aae !important;
height: 50px !important; position: relative !important; 
transition: 0.3s !important;}
```

HTML – Tab Pops Up & Changes Color

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td
height="60" align="center" valign="bottom"
style="vertical-align:bottom;">
<table class="grow" border="0" width="270" height="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#187395" align="center"><tr>
<td align="center" height="30" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; display:block; height: 30px;">
Pop-Up Tab
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a test with your code and the effect does work in Gmail desktop webmail for me. Gmail (desktop webmail) does support `:hover` (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-pseudo-class-hover/) but does not support `transition`, so the effect misses its animation.

Make sure your embedded CSS is in its own `<style>` in the `<head>` tag. Gmail doesn't support `<style>` in the `<body>`. Also, Gmail is notorious for removing an entire `<style>` tag if there’s a typo in its content so make sure the code you posted is in its own `<style>` tag in case you have other styles in your whole email.

Here’s the test code I used and sent through Mailchimp.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gmail</title>
    <style>
.grow {transition: 0.3s !important;} 
.grow:hover {background-color: #298aae !important;
height: 50px !important; position: relative !important; 
transition: 0.3s !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td
height="60" align="center" valign="bottom"
style="vertical-align:bottom;">
<table class="grow" border="0" width="270" height="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#187395" align="center"><tr>
<td align="center" height="30" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; display:block; height: 30px;">
Pop-Up Tab
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you a lot for checking this. Unfortunately, most users go with the web based (in browser) Gmail and the code you provided still leaves this approach ineffective -> I got no reaction. Apparently, I have to accept this is impossible to pull off.

Comment: I'm not sure of your answer. The example I posted does work in Gmail (desktop webmail) sent from Mailchimp. There might be something going on in your process (either in Mailchimp or in Gmail) that makes this not work. Feel free to share more infos for help.

Comment: Just to clarify - you put this as a code block and put it in the body/header section in MailChimp, right? I did a double check and sent it via MailChimp to my private Gmail account and no changes so it is not some blockage in the corporate email.

Comment: No, I did : Create > Regular Email > Content (Design Email) > Code your own > Paste in code. If you use a code block, the `<style>` tag will indeed be removed by Gmail as it will be embedded in the body.

Comment: Wow, it actually works this way! Thank you so much! Apparently there is something messed with the settings I had :)