# :hover works only in "code your own" in Mailchimp

Tags: css, email, hover, gmail, mailchimp

I was having an issue with :hover not working in MailChimp. Eventually, thanks to suggestion in this task: [I cannot make :hover work in the email sent to Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76329785/i-cannot-make-hover-work-in-the-email-sent-to-gmail-account/76330692#76330692) **I found it's possible, but apparently works only if you code your own email.**

Unfortunately, that's not the best solution as I would like to use the drag&drop functionality of MailChimp templates and **not code every email in pure HTML** - this is too time-consuming and I'm using this solution in a company where I work and also have 2 less technical people on board.

**Question: is there any way to make it work in the template view? So use the code block below, but also allow to easily edit other elements like text fields, etc.?**

MailChimp tech support is not open to help with this (even though I have the highest subscription option). **Thanks in advance for any help with that!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gmail</title>
    <style>
.grow {transition: 0.3s !important;} 
.grow:hover {background-color: #298aae !important;
height: 50px !important; position: relative !important; 
transition: 0.3s !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td
height="60" align="center" valign="bottom"
style="vertical-align:bottom;">
<table class="grow" border="0" width="270" height="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#187395" align="center"><tr>
<td align="center" height="30" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; display:block; height: 30px;">
Pop-Up Tab
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```